# Add image into UIAlertController in swift

Tags: image, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to have a simple UIAlertController with image in it. what should I do?

```
let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavailable", message: "Please retry later", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavailable", message: "Please retry later", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
var action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
alertMessage .addAction(action)

self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This effectively adds an image to the button area of an alert view. It's not the correct approach. Affects the button size and likely lacks accessibility. A custom alert is more effective in the absence of simple method provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

a snippet of code that works for me:

```
func alert2 (heading: String,image: String){
        if self.presentedViewController == nil {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil,     message: " ", preferredStyle: .Alert )
            var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 6, 300, 50))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: display.0)
            alertController.view.addSubview(imageView)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maps", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in self.makeContact("maps")}))
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my code to image in alert view

```
var logoAlert = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 250))
    logoAlert.image = UIImage(named: "v1.png")

    infoController.view.addSubview(logoAlert)
    NSLog("image is draw")
```

logoalert is dtring
infoController - is name of fun
rename it, and all will be alright
paste this code in fun of alert controller

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you edit your answer to contain a readable, English description (instead of "dtring", "fun"), it will be easier to understand and increase the chance of people voting for it. :-)

Comment: I don't know what you had before to get the down votes, but you fixed it and your code worked for me